# antmachers for webservices in spring security

Tags: web-services, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a list of webservices which requires authentication by doing

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

Is it possible to make the webservice permitted by someone how is not authenticated without being able to access webservice result from browser by doing 127.0.0.1/api/**

Comment: Would you please rephrase your last statement using shorter sentences.  It is not at all obvious to me, what you are asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta  for all my webservices i'm doing .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()  so  for consuming the webservice resulte you have to be authenticated,the probleme is for a specific webservice i want to be able to consume it without authentification.

Comment: Then configure it like so. What is the issue with that, just add an `permitAll` for that uri.

Comment: with permitAll u can access json result from browser /api/webservicename